# C# split a string by last space before each equal(=) symbol

Tags: c#, split

How to split the string by last space before symbol '='

For example I have the input string below and split by just space:

```
string inputName = "id=4 issue=critical level project=ABC group=Group A";
string[] values = inputName.Split(' ');
```

The result will be as below which is wrong :

```
id=4 
issue=critical 
level 
project=ABC 
group=Group 
A
```

But what i expected is :

```
id=4 
issue=critical level 
project=ABC 
group=Group A
```

So what i plan is search for symbol '=' and then split by the last space before each symbol '='

Comment: Better have a different separator other then space, like `,` or `;`. So keep the string like - `"id=4,issue=critical level,project=ABC,group=Group A"` and then split.

Comment: yes, but user insisted to input the data in this way. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Regex to split them:

```
string str = "id=4 issue=critical level project=ABC group=Group A";

var prefix = Regex.Matches(str, @"\w+=").ToList();

var values = Regex.Split(str, @"\w+=").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < prefix.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{prefix[i]}{values[i]}");
}
```

---

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi, how if for prefix now i want to take only the words before =

instead of id= take only id
instead of issue = take only issue

so the last result for Console.WriteLine( prefix[i]+"@"+values[i]}"); is like :
id@4
issue@critical level
project@ABC
group@Group

Answer (score 1):

Tân Nguyễn's answer is best.
Not knowing regex, I would have done something like the below:

```
var byEquals = inputName.Split("=");
var result = new Dictionary<String, String>();
for(int i = 0; i < byEquals.Length -1; i++)
{
result[byEquals[i].Split(" ").Last()] = String.Join(" ", byEquals[i + 1].Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
string inputName = "id=4 issue=critical level project=ABC group=Group A";
string[] values = inputName.Split(' ');
List<string> output = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length -1; i++)
{
    if (values[i].Contains('=') && !values[i + 1].Contains('='))
    {
         output.Add(values[i] + ' ' +values[i + 1]);
    }
    else if (!values[i].Contains('='))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        output.Add(values[i]);
    }
}

string[] requiredValues = output.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below thing will also work for you, **but for this I have just appended one space character after your EOS(End of String)**.

```
string s = "id=4 issue=critical level project=ABC group=Group A";
            s = s.Trim();
            s += " "; //TO MATCH THE REGEX
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w+=[\w\s]+\s");

             foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(s))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
```